# How to implement redirection to particular page after clicking on link in email in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Trying to implement a feature in Angular where user clicks on link provided in email and then redirect to respective page after authentication in Angular.I tried few things but nothing works.

So I tried following things :

(1) I tried to store query parameter in local storage to form URL and the tried to access those and generate link but local storage is gets cleared on that page for security reasons.

(2) I tried to store parameters in variable and store it in services which can be used to form URL. but variable gets cleared

but nothing works. Can some one help me .

Comment: add same code for better understanding and help you to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

You should provide complete URL of particular page in email.

Comment: yes I am getting that but after clicking on it and authentication i am redirected to dashboard instead of that page

Comment: then might be there is Auth Guard implemented on route of that page, which is preventing it to access.

Comment: I don't think so, because if I do same thing when i  am logged in then everything works fine but ont in logged out state

Comment: yes, then definitely Auth Guard is blocking your page. 
It checks and if you are logged out, it blocks you to access that page.
simple !! :)

You need to edit your Auth Guard then.

Comment: So i am new to angular i don't know about authentication  guard but in my project we have used HttpInterceptor .so can you help me with it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement a route guard that deals with your [deeplinks](https://angular.io/guide/router)
You should also provide code examples of what you've already done. It's possible that one of your previous attempts was correct but your implementation was flawed.

Comment: so the problem is i am getting complete links and after authentication i am redirected to dashboard